# How to open a Apache Maven project on NetBeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to open a project created with Apache Maven in NetBeans, with no success. I followed the directions given by this link: http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices but the Open Project dialog does not recognizes the project in the folder. When I point to the folder that contains the pom.xml file, it shows as if the folder is empty, except for the sub-folders. Apparently Apache Maven is disabled, but I can't find how to enable it.
Could someone point what is the mistake that I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please make sure the maven modules are actually installed in your distribution. (Tools/Plugins I believe). And the latest NetBeans version is 7.4, 7.0.1 is fairly old already.

Comment: According to the link that I showed, the Maven plugin is bundled with NetBeans since the version 7.0. I installed the 7.0.1 because is the one that was in the repository of Lubuntu 13.10. Indeed the plugin does not show up when looking into Tools/Plugins/Installed, but I couldn't find any directions to install the plugin in NetBeans 7.0 and above (since it is said to be already bundled). Maybe I try to follow the instructions for a older version of NetBeans?

Comment: I tried to create a new project since the link says that the Maven plugin has to be used to be enabled, but the New Project dialog shows no categories (only "Please Wait").

Comment: I'm personally sceptical towards the netbeans bits provided by the linux distros (jdk as well mostly). I think it better to install directly from netbeans site.

Comment: My guess is that they strip most features that they could have problems with licensing, besides that they compile by themselves with compiling options that may not be optimal.I always had problems with java and Linux and java on low end machines and that kept me away from mastering java properly.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the NetBeans 7.4 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html and it worked! Probably the build from Ubuntu repositories has issues. Thanks for the suggestions!